# Aironet 1252 not booting

Tags: cisco, wifi

I have a 1252 Aironet AP that does not boots up.
I've plugged the console cable, but displays nothing.
After connecting power via PoE, I just got the radio LED on red after 5 seconds.

I've checked the LED status, but this state seems not to be documented: [Cisco Aironet 1200 series LED status](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/1250/installation/guide/1250HIG_TD-Book-Wrapper/125h_c3.html#wp1077466)

If I hold the MODE button in order to perform factory reset, nothing happens.

Any ideas what may be wrong? and how may I attempt to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/1250/installation/guide/1250HIG_TD-Book-Wrapper/125h_c3.html#wp1111349), Red Radio LED means the board is initialising.

Does the LED status change after some time? Do you see more red LEDs or combinations of others? The guide above should help you to diagnose.

In order to factory reset, you usually need to hold the mode button when the device is powered off, plug in the power and continue holding until the status LED also turns red (Ethernet remains off). This usually takes a hold of 20-30s.

3 Red LEDs is RAM failure. I'd recommend an RMA if possible - the device has been End of Sale for a while.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The radio LED stays red all the time, no change even after waiting for a long time. I've tried the factory reset, but the system just does not boots up. Looks like it is doing nothing, not a single LED flashing nor nothing.

Comment: Must be dead then... or not getting past the diagnostic phase. Usually I'd suggest a corrupted image but seems this goes beyond that into a corrupted ROMMON to the point where even an image restore will not help. Bad news all around I'm afraid.